# Extracting values from a JSON string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to retrieve the different tag values in an NSString.

```
NSString *test      =  

{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "100002319144563_125257217561582",
            "from": {
                "name": "Umair Ahmed",
                "id": "100002319144563"
            },
            "message": "Hello Umair Here",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "name": "Comment",
                    "link": "http://www.facebook.com/100002319144563/posts/125257217561582"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Like",
                    "link": "http://www.facebook.com/100002319144563/posts/125257217561582"
                }
            ],
            "privacy": {
                "description": "Everyone",
                "value": "EVERYONE"
            },
            "type": "status",
            "application": {
                "name": "iPhone",
                "id": "213257025359930"
            },
            "created_time": "2011-07-08T11:59:15+0000",
            "updated_time": "2011-07-08T11:59:15+0000"
        },
        {
            "id": "100002319144563_125251050895532",
            "from": {
                "name": "Umair Ahmed",
                "id": "100002319144563"
            },
            "message": "Hello testing testing",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "name": "Comment",
                    "link": "http://www.facebook.com/100002319144563/posts/125251050895532"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Like",
                    "link": "http://www.facebook.com/100002319144563/posts/125251050895532"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I retrieve the name and message tag values into an array or dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a JSON string, so just use one of JSON libraries, like [TouchJSON](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON) or [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) and you can easily extract the data from the structures they will provide you.